# Find the value of expression

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I was preparing for Olympiad then I got this question and I don't understand how to solve.

$a,b,c$ are real no such that $a-7b+8c=4$and $8a+4b-c=7$ find$$a^2-b^2+c^2$$

Comment: The answer by @Rohan is exactly what I was going to post. In general, you can't solve such systems (3 unknowns, but only two equations), but the problem implies that you can in this particular case, so you seek to manipulate your other two equations to have the form of the desired expression.

Comment: @TheCount You are in fact not able to solve it even in this particular case as it has infinitely many solutions, it is just that all those solutions will have same value of $a^2-b^2+c^2$.

Comment: @Ashwani, you are posting problem after problem without providing any of your own thoughts or progress. Your latest questions have already been answered on this site, so you might find it helpful to search for them first before posting. You have also altered your posts after they have proven to be duplicates. It would also be respectful if you put in some time to format your posts so that they are more readable.

Comment: @Sil, well that was what I meant, but that's a fair point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rearranging, we get $a+8c=7b+4$ and $8a-c=7-4b$

Squaring both,we have, $a^2+16ac+64c^2=49b^2+56b+16$ and $64a^2-16ac+c^2=16b^2-56b+49$.

Adding the two equations and dividing by $65$ gives $a^2+c^2 = b^2+1$ so $$a^2-b^2+c^2 = 1$$